# GSM MQTT Subscribe

Tags: mqtt, gsm

I want to subscribe a topic from my mqtt broker using a GSM Modem. I am new to GSM modem, Please guide me to implement this.

Based on my under standing, I need to follow these steps.

1. Prepare modem using Basic AT commands
2. Start TCP connection to MQTT broker using ATcommands ( Say: AT+ CIPSTART="TCP","MQTT BROKER","MQTT PORT"
3. Send Subscribe message to MQTT broker ( AT + CIPSEND and remaining steps )
4. Then In a loop continuously read serial buffer data. If connection closed reconnect.

Please confirm my understandings are correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gsm800 mqtt library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816759/gsm800-mqtt-library)

Comment: Also there is no way this can be a Bluemix question as there is no way to physically attach a GSM module to an app running in the cloud